# How to parse these html string in objective c

Tags: html, objective-c, parsing, tags, nsstring

I'm getting an string from json response. In the string there are HTML tags,

```
<ul class='video-list-container'><li><a href='?page_id=6602&playid=6'>مكتبة الفيديو</a></li><li><a href='?page_id=6602&playid=10'>الزكاة</a></li><li><a href='?page_id=6602&playid=11'>الصلاة</a></li></ul>\n
```

Now all I want to do is to do is, get the arabic string with the href link and display in the `UITableviewcell`. And when selected row should move to next viewcontroller.

How can do this. I'm struck in parsing the string.
Can anyone help me.
Thanks In advance.

Comment: check these [link1](https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser) [link2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios)

Comment: Also, http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/parsing-an-xml-file/

Comment: @pawan that din work.

Answer (score 1):

I think this tutorials might help you ,

AFNetworking is smart enough to load and process structured data over the network, as well as plain old HTTP requests. In particular, it supports JSON, XML and Property Lists (plists).

you can follow the tutorial given below  for more clarification

http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the library "hpple" which is a wrapper around "libxml2". You can find hpple [here](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple).

Hpple allows you to parse HTML in Obj-C using XPath expressions. With XPath selectors you will be able to select what content you want to extract out of your HTML. You can read and learn more about XPath [here](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/).

Hope it helps. :)

Cheers!